# How to get rid of the background grid lines appearing in Oracle JET bar chart?

Tags: knockout.js, oracle-jet

I am trying to get a oracle jet bar chart in my html page as mentioned [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=barChart&demo=dataLabels):
I am able to get that up correctly.
However, I don't want the grid lines appearing in the graph in the background.
Is there any option to get rid of them?

Comment: Select _Plot Area Styles_ tab [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=barChart&demo=styles) and set lineWidth to 0 for Y-axis

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of the grid lines using below code. 0 - to hide the lines, change this value to increase the width.

```
self.yAxis = ko.pureComputed(function() {
          return {
            majorTick: {
              lineWidth: 0,
            }
          };
        });
```

And set this in html

```
y-axis="[[yAxis]]"
```